# Is my car safe to drive?

Tags: nissan

[image: ![<code>enter image description here</code>]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIo52.jpg)

[image]

When I make a right turn it hear a loud noise .

EDIT for OP: Well it's a Nissan altima 05 . Every time I make a right turn i hear this metal noise . I check my wheels and only me right side has that hole so I figured that's what's causing that noise

Comment: Adding as much information as you can will help someone help you.  What's year/make/model?  Are you on the gas, off the gas, coasting?  Does it happen on the freeway.  How much do you have to turn?  What does the clunking sound like?  Can you feel it in your floorboards?  Can you feel it in your steering wheel?  Please describe the issue in the most detailed fashion you can.   Cheers!   :-)

Comment: In a word: NO. Not a chance. At least not until we get more information. You've given us nothing to go on here.

Comment: Well it's a Nissan altima 05 . Every time I make a full turn i hear this loud noise on the left side. A friend of  mine told me it was the power steering

Comment: Here's a link to a tour to help you understand how this site works.   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour   Also, click around to some of the other questions and see what you can do to get a better description of what you are experiencing into the question.   I don't think someone is going to be able to determine if "your car is safe to drive" with the limited info you have provided.  I'm not sure what 'hole' your even referring to.

Comment: Well if you look inside the spring there's a hole but thanks

Comment: I added a zoomed in pictured of what I'm talking about

Comment: What kind of noise is it? Continuous while turning? A loud thump? A squeal? What is it?

Comment: Yes it's like a loud rusty sound. My car still turns but it makes this sounds . When I turn my whole  steering I hear that sound

Comment: I described the sound to my father over the phone and he said it could be the ball joints

Answer (score 2):

Not a great lot to go on, but it does sound like a siezed bearing at the top of the strut.  Because the bearing is not able to rotate, the Spring is forced to slide across it's mounting which it does suddenly causing a loud 'twang' noise.  The hole in the cover in your photo will have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I recently got my engine switch . But if that's the problem,  what's the estimate to get it fixed ?

Comment: Or the ball joints?

Comment: While the car is stationary, get someone to turn the steering wheel from fully left to fully right while you watch the spring, see if it suddenly jumps and makes a noise.  I don't know how much it would cost to repair.